# How can I know if all chars are capitalized in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

How can I find out if all letters are capitalized in a string?

Like:

```
var someVar = 'AAAAA DDSSS asssd';
```

Or just more than 80% of letters are capitalized?

Comment: What's your opinion of the general procedure?

Comment: All is easy, you call `.toUpperCase()` on your string and see if it’s equal to the original. For “more than 80%” you’ll have to loop through the characters, count the upper chars and calculate the percentage with the string length …

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if all the letters in a string are capital recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959883/check-if-all-the-letters-in-a-string-are-capital-recursively)

Comment: I'm perhaps biased, but I'm voting to reopen as the question seems clear enough to be answered, and 'understanding' of the underlying issues/problems can be difficult for newcomers to JavaScript. Though while I agree that some pseudo-code might be easily-enough shown, I'd argue that the question is neither 'off-topic' (there's a clear programming question), nor a duplicate of the linked question (if only because of the different language being used).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function capitalized (str) {
    var len = str.length,
        noCapitals = str.replace(/[a-z]/g,''),
        percent = (noCapitals.length/len) * 100;
    return percent;
}
var someVar = 'AAAAA DDSSS addes',
    p = capitalized(someVar);
console.log(p);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m2pkd/1/).

Or, if you'd like to have fixed-accuracy:

```
function capitalized (str) {
    var len = str.length,
        noCapitals = str.replace(/[a-z]/g,''),
        percent = (noCapitals.length/len) * 100;
    return parseFloat(percent.toFixed(2));
}
var someVar = 'AAAAA DDSSS addes',
    p = capitalized(someVar);
console.log(p);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m2pkd/2/).

And slightly more useful (in that it we also strip out white-space as well as lowercase), with a simple check to avoid performing unnecessary math:

```
function capitalized (str) {
    var len = str.length,
        noCapitals = str.replace(/[a-z]\s/g,''),
        percent = noCapitals.length === 0 ? 100 : (noCapitals.length/len) * 100;
    return parseFloat(percent.toFixed(2));
}
var someVar = 'AAAAA    DDSSS',
    p = capitalized(someVar);
console.log(p);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m2pkd/3/).

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).
- [`String.parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Assumes an ASCII definition of "capital", but probably correct for this question.

Comment: True enough, and honestly I hadn't thought about the ASCII-assumption. I'll think about that, now... =)

Comment: May be this will be a bit more accurate and suitable for custom definitions of 'letter' and 'capital': example for Latin and Cyrillic letters — http://jsfiddle.net/m2pkd/5/

Comment: Maybe we can convince ES6 to implement [POSIX character classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) that guarantee locale-specific lexical correctness. ;) Or maybe not.

Comment: @Kojiro: I'm still trying to work out a way to get a `:last-of-class()`/`:nth-last-of-class()` selector proposed for CSS...TC39 seems beyond my access, or ken. =(

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
if (myString == myString.toUpperCase())
{
  alert('all upper case');
}
```

This will check for complete upper case string. If you want to check like 80% then you need to do some mathematics logic with loop over every character.